# OffsetWidth / offsetHeight is zero when template loaded by ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have a template (partial view of a bigger html, mapped using angular route) with this code:

```
<div  style="width: 100% !important; max-width: 1000px; height: auto !important;">
       <canvas id="barChart">
        </canvas>
</div>
```

On angular's controller initalization, I create a chart with this code:

```
$scope.chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d")).StackedBar(chartData, opts);
```

The problem is, that when I access my page by refreshing (URL) the chart gets drawn, but when I access the page via ngRoute (clicking on menu items just draw the central part template), the chart is not drawn. I debugged into Chart.js and find out that this code runs differently when accessing the page via template:

```
if (element['offset'+dimension])
        {
            return element['offset'+dimension];
        }
        else
        {
            return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(dimension);
        }
```

When I access via URL / refreshing, the offsetWidth property is set on the canvas element. When I access via angular's route mechanism, the offsetWidth is not set, and the document.defaultView... is executed returning 0, so the chart does not get drawn.

Comment: The difference between your 2 different types of access is that ngRoute uses Ajax to load your page, so I think it is possible that your 'new Chart' is called before the DOM of the view is actually ready. For troubleshooting, I recommend you to try a $timeout before calling 'new Chart', or to use this Chart.js wrapper for AngularJS : http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by recreating the canvas on each controller's initialization. I didn't try the solution posted by @bviale:

```
getChartContext = function(id, width, height) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
  var canvasParent = canvas.parentNode;
  canvas.remove();
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = id;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvasParent.appendChild(canvas);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  return ctx;
};
```